# Collapsible Bootstrap4 accordion not working as i expecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my code i tried to design a e-commerce checkout page .First one panel would be opened and when first step is completed and click action button it would unfreeze the next panel and so on.But somehow i'm doing mistake so that it is not working out.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.action').click(function() {

    var tab_id = $(this).attr('href');

    $('#' + tab_id).parent('.card').removeClass('NotactiveDiv').addClass('activeDiv');

  });

});
```

```css
.card:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

.card:last-child .card-header {
  border-bottom: 0px solid #d7d7d7;
}

.card {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #d7d7d7;
}

.card h5 a {
  color: #616161;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.card h5 a:hover {
  color: #616161;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

.card h5 {
  outline: none;
}

.card-header {
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #d7d7d7;
  outline: none;
}

.NotactiveDiv {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

  <div class="card activeDiv">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                 1. Account Verification <span><img src="img/greentick.png"> </span>
                </a>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="card-block">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.<br/>
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" class="action">
                    ACTIONS
                  </a>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card NotactiveDiv">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
         2. Delivery Details <span><img src="img/greentick.png"> </span>
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="card-block">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.<br/>
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree" class="action">
            ACTIONS
          </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card NotactiveDiv">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
         3. Payment Method <span><img src="img/greentick.png"> </span>
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="card-block">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.<br/>
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="collapseFour" class="action">
            ACTIONS
          </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card NotactiveDiv">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingFour">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
         4. Review Order <span><img src="img/greentick.png"> </span>
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="collapseFour">
      <div class="card-block">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.<br/>
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#" class="action">
            ACTIONS
          </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Please help me.I want when the action button of the current panel is clickd then next panel would open and current panel would be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something must exist already.

Having said that, your code should work like this:

```
    $('.action').click(function(){ 

        $(this).closest(".card")
          .removeClass('activeDiv')
          .addClass('NotactiveDiv')
          .children('.collapse').removeClass('show');

       $(this).closest(".card").next('.card')
          .removeClass('NotactiveDiv')
          .addClass('activeDiv');        
   });
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks but you see whn you click action btn the next div opening very fast which should be open lil slowly and 2nd is when you click are on the 2nd or 3rd or 4th panel you can't access the first panel

Comment: I don't think you can change the bootstrap collapsing panel speed. Also, having more content on each panel, will make the effect look better. However, looking on the documentation, I found that there's no need to close the current panel with Jquery as we did in the example. You can keep the event handler for adding/removing your clases **NotactiveDiv** and **activeDiv**, but I think there's no need to remove the class **show**. Take a look at this example: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/#example